# Files, "real" access time when copy from remote host

Tags: files, stat

**Question.**.
Is possible to dig "real" access time of file copied from remote server and using it by including from another script?

**What I need.**
I need to know which files on server are unused/untouched for long time, but I have only ftp access, so I must download files. Curlftps not solve this.
And what about files only included from another file, for example include in php script? Does included file change his access time when is accessed by include from another script?
***Edited.***
Tested included file access time change, it change access time when file is "touched" by include script.

**Tested**
When I copied the file, there was quite strange access time, file should be accessed very often.

```
hosek@yoga:~/www/html/__test$ stat rest.php 
  File: rest.php
  Size: 26312       Blocks: 56         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 1739998     Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/   hosek)   Gid: ( 1000/   hosek)
Access: 2018-05-24 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2018-05-24 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2019-07-03 12:46:58.724173058 +0200
 Birth: -
hosek@yoga:~/www/html/__test$
```

Thank you.

***Edited.***
Just info, that when I connect via sshfs or curlftps, seems that display right access date, but time is only at 0, which is ok for me. Is this date real or am I wrong? And is Access time "real"? Thanks.

```
  File: ./rest.php
  Size: 26312       Blocks: 56         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 23          Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
 Birth: -
  File: ./robots.txt
  Size: 277         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 24          Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2018-05-24 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
 Birth: -
  File: ./svn.txt
  Size: 32          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 25          Links: 1
Access: (0666/-rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-06-30 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2016-06-30 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
Change: 2016-06-30 01:00:00.000000000 +0200
 Birth: -
```